# Error: Invalid Chai property: revertedWith on Hardhat

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, solidity, chai, hardhat

Currently working on hardhat using chai also

```
const {assert, expect} = require("chai")
const {deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts, network} = require("hardhat")
const {developmentChains} = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
   it("Fails if you don't send enough ETH", async function () {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more eth"
            )
        })
```

Thats my source code but i get this error

```
   FundMe
       withdraw
         is allows us to withdraw with multiple funders:
     Error: Invalid Chai property: reverted
```

Comment: did you install this: @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10262805/yilmaz who helped

i was able to fix it by installing

```
# yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers
```

And i also added this

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers")
```

on my hardhat.config.js